# x64 VC11 builds of PHP5 and Apache2 not playing nice on Windows

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, php, 64-bit

Here is the Apache I am using: http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=24281 (httpd-2.4.4-win64-VC11.zip)

And here is the version of PHP I am using: [http://windows.php.net/download/](http://windows.php.net/download/#x64) (VC11 x64 Non Thread Safe (2013-Jun-20 02:50:14))

My php.ini is configured correctly, as is httpd.conf, however after I add the following lines to get Apache to load PHP:

```
PHPIniDir "c:/php5" 
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php5/php5.dll" 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php5
```

I get the following error when I try to start the server:

```
Syntax error on line 527 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `php5_module' in file C:/php5/php5.dll
```

I don't get what's wrong, I have the 64-bit versions of PHP and Apache, and they are both compiled using VC11. Why doesn't Apache like PHP's dll file?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using the wrong DLL.  Usually there will be a php5apache2_2.dll or a php5apache2_4.dll which expresses the SAPI for apache and is usable as an apache module.

That said, you really should avoid WAMP stacks for many, many reasons: linux is effectively the primary development and support OS for both apache and php, and historically dev involvement in windows-only bugs and issues is scant.  Moreover, the licensing costs for linux are lower, as is the performance overhead.

Comment: I agree with you that Linux is better for this, and infact it is what I use the vast majority of the time, but it's just not an option in this specific case. The strange thing is, the version of Apache I am using was Linked to explicitly from the PHP page, so I feel like it should be the correct dll :\ there is no php5apache2.dll included in the package I downloaded, just php5.dll. I will keep playing around though.

Comment: You may have the wrong package then.  There should be an apache-specific module.

Answer (score 0):

The correct dll was in the thread-safe version of php; php-5.5.0-Win32-VC11-x64.zip